# summary of activites each employee does

Tags: php, mysql, sql, arrays

i had a database which contain 2 different tables.

1. about my employees such as salesman1, salesman2, salesman3
2. about their activities with dates such as call, walkin enquiry, testing, visit .

so how do i able to display my finding in a table on how many 
call, walkin enquiry, testing, visit of salesman1 from certain dates likewise for salesman2 and salesman3?

example of the table which show my findings is like below

Desired output:

```
Activities From 01/04/2014 - 13/04/2014
salesman1

--------------------------------------------
| calls | walkin enquiry | testing | visit |
--------------------------------------------    
| 4     | 5              | 3       | 15    |
--------------------------------------------
```

In this form?
Thank in advance =)

Comment: is it your second table consist salemanid?

Comment: yes 2nd id consist of salemanid

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
select t2.salesmanid, count(t2.call), count(t2.walkin_enquiry),count(t2.testing), count(t2.visit)
from 1st_table t1, 2nd_table t2
where date BETWEEN 1/04/2014 AND 15/04/20014 and t1.salemanid = t2.salemanid
group by salemanid;
```